# Cordova navigator.camera.getPicture returns FILE_URI in unexpected format on Android 4.4 KitKat from gallery

Tags: android, cordova, android-4.4-kitkat

Before Kitkat navigator.camera.getPicture returned a Uri like this

`content://media/external/images/media/3951`.

In Kitkat however it returns a Uri like this:

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:3951
```

Example code using cordova-2.9.0:

```
gallery: function () {
  navigator.camera.getPicture(this.handleUri,
    function () {
      console.log('error retrieving imageURI');
      return false;
    },
    { quality: 100,
      destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY }
  );
},

handleUri: function (imageURI) {
  //imageURI is in unexpected format content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:3951            
}
```

How do we return the URI in the original format?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothin wring with the URL.

It is no file URL it is a Content-URL. You should be able to work with that URL as well. If not, you may have to use a [Content-Resolver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html).

What do you want to do with the URL? And what does note work?

Comment: I want to show the image in a cropper in the webview. The new uri does not work as expected, and breaks my app in 4.4. Cordova does not provide a Content-Reslover handler, so I believe that I have to develop a plugin with that functionality.

Answer (score -1):

use destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL instead of  destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI 
and add com.simplec.plugins.externalfiles plugin to your config.xml
or

Update your Cordova to 3.5 this fixes all Kitkat issues

Comment: This is a poor answer.  DATA_URL is extremely memory intensive and will cause the app to crash in many situations.